# Where can I get a list of unused access keys?

Tags: html, accessibility, access-keys

I'd like to know what access keys I can use for my site.  Anyone know where I can find a list?  Also, I understand that the UK has a standard.  Is anyone familiar with a site that lists standard access keys for other countries (for example, Japan)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The British or UK standard is actually the only standard that ever reached a certain popularity and is used throughout the world as the one standard. The default layout is

```
S - Skip navigation
1 - Home page
2 - What’s new
3 - Site map
4 - Search
5 - Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)
6 - Help
7 - Complaints procedure
8 - Terms and conditions
9 - Feedback form
0 - Access key details
```

Besides that, access keys can be a barrier in itself which is why some usability experts advise to not use them (search for John Foliot's arguments).

Comment: I second Paul's comments. Once you get into using letters, you run into interfering with browser's and assistive technology's commands, which overrule accesskeys. Thus your options get limited to like 5 or 6 characters, which is something like G,Q,X,Y and Z. Which not many sites I know have sections starting with those characters.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm not necessarily thinking of 'access keys'.  S.O. uses `ctrl+k` for code and `ctrl+l` to add a new list item, etc.  If those aren't access keys, what kind of hotkeys are they?  How can I know which of these hotkeys are free and which aren't?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08, Access keys are `alt+[character]`. They are usually added to links or form elements to allow you to jump there without having to tab through the whole page to get to them. If you look at Paul's list, the items defined are items considered in a header section or navigation section of a site. Look at [comment 8 in this blog post](http://clagnut.com/blog/193/), while it _is_ dated, the information is still correct.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Then you're talking of shortcuts? Shortcut keys maybe? Accesskeys are (were?) very specific to disabled users (and are being replaced by ARIA landmark roles in very recent websites and screen readers). Shortcuts are OK for power users like a SO user but'll annoy like hell a screen reader user if (s)he can't disable them. If you've ever seen the list of shortcuts in Photoshop, well it's the same in JAWS or NVDA! Every letter alone or in combination wth Alt, Shift and Ctrl are already taken. Ouch.

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations Oh sweet.  Thanks, man.  I think that being able to disable stuff is of key importance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the list of access keys that you can use: . (The “.” is a full stop that terminates the sentence; it is not meant to refer to an access key.)

Any keys that you can use are in some pre-assigned use in some browsers. One of the reasons is that the user interface language of a browser varies, so any letter key is probably used as a shortcut for some browser command. In addition, access keys are used by assistive software and other programs that might be involved when using a browser.

Using digit keys as access keys probably minimizes the problem, as digit keys are not normally used in browsers—but they might be used by other software, possibly for crucial tasks.